# Display available apps on SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-pages

Can I see somehow how the O365 pages are built up? Not the html sent to the client, but the source aspx code? I need to present the same "available apps" links to the current user on a SharePoint online (modern site). 
I didn't find such a web part, and I would like to know how can I embed that in an "embed" web part. 
To make clear, I'd like to present the same application icons on a sharepoint online site that are on O365 start page of the same tenant, the same way it is also visible to the actual user: 
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to embed this on a page? Clicking the app launcher should display most of these apps on the menu that appears.  Users can pin frequently used apps as well.  Not sure I see the benefit in adding these icons to a page when they're available on any SharePoint page already.

Comment: It is one click less :) This is on the sketch and I need to build it. I said ok, because it didn't look like a challange to embedd what is already there on another page in he same environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think SharePoint is a part of Office 365 that integrates other apps, but I don't think you'll be able to call items from the Office 365 Portal/ Azure tenant (Or apps like OneDrive) natively.

You will probably need to create custom links to each item (or use promoted links), but I would recommend just linking to the Office Portal from SharePoint. Even if you come up with an elegant looking solution a future update will probably break it.

If you insist on embedded app links dynamically linked to the O365 portal I would suggest embedding the Application window in an iframe is the easiest solution.

Comment: "Application window in an iframe" And how do I do that? I guess, with the "Embed" web part, and I need an url of an embed code. Where can I find this?

Comment: you can just use the embed script web part and use the html <iframe> tag:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

bearing in mind that to display correctly you'll need to adjust position and overflow (overflow/ scrolling can be set in app part settings)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587823/iframe-positioning

Comment: That one I know, but how do I find out the embed code for the application window?

Comment: Or did you mean to embed the whole office.com site and try to reposition and resize it in the iframe until it looks good?

Comment: Either of your suggested approaches would work, but you are extending your question beyond it's original scope. Please ask a new question.

Comment: The original question is how can I embed the application links to a sharepoint page, and it is still open, because I still don't know what code shall I put to the embed webpart :(

Comment: It's still open because there are multiple different approaches to achieve this. For specific code on how to embed the object using an iframe, start a new question. Otherwise read up on how to use stack exchange.

Comment: Disagree. From the post: " I would like to know how can I embed that in an "embed" web part. " Answering "iframe" has no value added, because currently iframe is the only way to embed external content in an embed webpart.

Comment: No value added but you came up with two possible solutions on your own using the suggestion? Wow...

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer seeing as the OP is unhappy with an iframe is to use jquery to replace in injected div with the required div of the remote location.

```
$('#target-div').load('https://www.office.com#officeHome__content')
```

If you need to refine the section to a class you can use `div.tiles-section__container`or `div.standard-tiles` or just inspect element on what you would like to import.

No idea if SharePoint security policies will allow the remote content though

Comment: Hm, I think, I need to apologize because most likely my screenshot is misleading, and probably both solutions do what that shows, but what I want is, what the text says: only the application icons (all of them, just as the user would see on the office page) in the embed webpart, not the rest of the office screen.

Comment: That's what this is designed to do because all of those office icons are wrapped in a div on the office.com site. It just uses js and html instead of the aspx you asked for.